# Returning original collection type in generic method

Tags: generics, scala, collections

Say we want to make a function like `minBy` that returns all elements of equal minimalism in a collection:

```
def multiMinBy[A, B: Ordering](xs: Traversable[A])(f: A => B) = {
  val minVal = f(xs minBy f)
  xs filter (f(_) == minVal)
}

scala> multiMinBy(List("zza","zzza","zzb","zzzb"))(_.last)
res33: Traversable[java.lang.String] = List(zza, zzza)
```

So far, so good, except that we have a `Traversable` back instead of our initial `List`.

So I tried changing the signature to

```
def multiMinBy[A, B: Ordering, C <: Traversable[A]](xs: C)(f: A => B)
```

in the hope I might get a `C` back rather than a `Traversable[A]`. However, I don't get anything back:

```
scala> multiMinBy(List("zza","zzza","zzb","zzzb"))(_.last)

<console>:9: error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,List[java.lang.String]] 
do not conform to method multiMinBy's type parameter bounds [A,B,C <: Traversable[A]]
```

I think this is because we have `C` appearing in the arguments before `A` has been inferred? So I flipped the order of the arguments, and added a cast:

```
def multiMinBy[A, B: Ordering, C <: Traversable[A]](f: A => B)(xs: C) = {
  val minVal = f(xs minBy f)
  (xs filter (f(_) == minVal)).asInstanceOf[C]
}
```

which works, except we have to call it like this:

```
multiMinBy((x: String) => x.last)(List("zza","zzza","zzb","zzzb"))
```

Is there a way to retain the original syntax, while getting the right collection type back?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think Miles Sabin solution is way too complex. Scala's collection already have the necessary machinery to make it work, with a very small change:

```
import scala.collection.TraversableLike
def multiMinBy[A, B: Ordering, C <: Traversable[A]]
              (xs: C with TraversableLike[A, C])
              (f: A => B): C = {
  val minVal = f(xs minBy f)
  xs filter (f(_) == minVal)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is a better solution than mine.

Comment: Can you explain why you have to use GreaterLowerBound: `C with TraversableLike[A, C]`. How did you know this was needed in order for the method to return C? I don't think I understand where the specific type of the input is saved

Comment: @Adrian With Scala 2.13, that might not even be true anymore. In fact, I doubt it is. The `Traversable[A]` bound granted methods that depend only on the type of the item, `A`. `TraversableLike[A, C]` grants methods that not only handle type item type `A`, but _return the type `C`. Since it's `C with TraversableLike[A,C]`, it means I can call a method on it and it will return the same collection `C`, instead of, say, returning `Traversable[A]`. That's the case of the `filter` method, which, without this bound, would not return `C`.

Comment: ah so this with does union oh methods (methods from Traversable[A] and from TraversableLike[A, C])

Comment: @Adrian Not so much union of _methods_, but unification of types. The same method (filter) exists in both, but the return type on `TraversableLike` is more specific. I might have used _just_ `TraversableLike`, but I'm guessing -- I don't really remember -- that the type inference just didn't work if I did so.

Answer (score 13):

How about using `CanBuildFrom`?

```
import scala.collection.immutable._
import scala.collection.generic._

def multiMinBy[A, B, From[X] <: Traversable[X], To](xs: From[A])(f: A => B)
  (implicit ord: Ordering[B], bf: CanBuildFrom[From[_], A, To])  = {
  val minVal = f(xs minBy f)
  val b = bf()
  b ++= (xs filter (f(_) == minVal))
  b.result
} 



scala> multiMinBy(List("zza","zzza","zzb","zzzb"))(_.last)
res1: List[java.lang.String] = List(zza, zzza)
```

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is that when viewed as a method on `GenTraversable[A]` (which I'll use instead of `Traversable[A]` in this answer) the result type of the `filter` method is no more precise than `GenTraversable[A]`. Unfortunately within the body of the `multiMinBy` method as written that's all you know about `xs`.

To get the result you're after you'll have to make the signature of `multiMinBy` more precise. One way of doing this while still leaving the container type relatively open is to use a structural type as follows,

```
type HomFilter[CC[X] <: GenTraversable[X], A] = 
  CC[A] { def filter(p : A => Boolean) : CC[A] }

def multiMinBy[CC[X] <: GenTraversable[X], A, B: Ordering]
  (xs: HomFilter[CC, A])(f: A => B) : CC[A] = {
    val minVal = f(xs minBy f)
    xs filter (f(_) == minVal)
  }
```

The structural type `HomFilter` allows us to assert that the argument to `multiMinBy` must have a `filter` method with the desired result type.

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> val mmb = multiMinBy(List("zza","zzza","zzb","zzzb"))(_.last)
mmb: List[String] = List(zza, zzza)
```

Bear in mind that this is a stricter requirement than that the container just be `Traversable`: it's permissible for subtypes of `GenTraversable` to define `filter` methods which aren't regular in this way. The signature above will statically prevent values of such types from being passed to `multiMinBy` ... presumably that's the behaviour you're after.

Comment: One can avoid the whole structural typing thingy just by using `TraversableLike`.