# Returning same collection type, differently parameterised

Tags: generics, scala, collections, scala-collections

Daniel Sobral showed how we can create a method that returns the same collection type upon which it was called in his answer to this question: [Returning original collection type in generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8235462/770361)

Is it possible to do the same for a method that uses a mapping to return a differently-parameterized version of the same collection type?

For example

```
def foo[A](xs: GenTraversable[A]) = xs map (_.toString)
```

`foo( List(1, 2, 3) )` returns `res: GenTraversable[String] = List(1, 2, 3)`

Can this be adapted so that

`foo( Set(1, 2, 3) )` returns a `Set[String]`

`foo( List(1, 2, 3) )` returns a `List[String]`

`foo( Vector(1, 2, 3) )` returns a `Vector[String]`

Comment: Since erasure removes your type parameters, you asserts are quite easy to pass. `def foo[T](x:T) = x` works

Comment: @huitseeker good point, thanks; my intention was not really to pass asserts but to write a method that does the correct thing, so I've edited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extending Daniel's answer to the linked question:

```
def foo[A,T[X] <: TraversableLike[X,T[X]]](xs: T[A])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[T[A],String,T[String]]):  T[String] = xs.map(_.toString)
```

Note that the [`map` method defined in `TraversableLike`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.1/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L191-196) takes an implicit [`CanBuildFrom`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.1/src/library/scala/collection/generic/CanBuildFrom.scala) parameter.
This is used to create a builder for the desired collection type so it has to be parameterized the way it is in the code (i.e., based on a collection of type `T[A]`, build a `T[String]` from `String` elements).

Comment: Well, yes, but you really ought to explain why `CanBuildFrom` needs to be there.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I have the feeling that this should be a lot easier; perhaps the lesson is that instead of passing collections to methods, we should map to functions, with the processing defined in the function rather than a method.

Comment: this doesn't work in Scala 2.9.2 :-( The compile error is a type mismatch; it sees TraversableOnce[Any] coming back from the map, and wants a T[String].