# Working with scala collections - CanBuildFrom trouble

Tags: scala, collections

I'm trying to write a method which accepts any type of collection `CC[_]` and maps it to a new collection (the same collection type but a different element type) and I am struggling royally. Basically I'm trying to implement `map` but *not on the collection itself*.

### The Question

I'm trying to implement a method with a signature which looks a bit like:

```
def map[CC[_], T, U](cct: CC[T], f: T => U): CC[U]
```

It's usage would be:

```
map(List(1, 2, 3, 4), (_ : Int).toString) //would return List[String]
```

I'm interested in an answer which would also work where `CC` is `Array` and I'm interested in the reason my attempts (below) have ultimately not worked.

---

### My Attempts

*(For the impatient, in what follows, I utterly fail to get this to work. To reiterate, **the question** is "how can I write such a method?")*

I start like this:

```
scala> def map[T, U, CC[_]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[T], U, CC[U]]): CC[U] = 
     | cct map f
                                                             ^
 <console>:9: error: value map is not a member of type parameter CC[T]
       cct map f
           ^
```

OK, that makes sense - I need to say that `CC` is traversable!

```
scala> def map[T, U, X, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[T], U, CC[U]]): CC[U] = 
     | cct map f
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Traversable[U]
 required: CC[U]
       cct map f
           ^
```

Err, OK! Maybe if I actually specify that `cbf` instance. After all, it specifies the return type (`To`) as `CC[U]`:

```
scala> def map[T, U, X, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[T], U, CC[U]]): CC[U] = 
     | cct.map(t => f(t))(cbf)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[CC[T],U,CC[U]]
 required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Traversable[T],U,CC[U]]
       cct.map(t => f(t))(cbf)
                          ^
```

Err, OK! That's a more specific error. Looks like I can use that!

```
scala> def map[T, U, X, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Traversable[T], U, CC[U]]): CC[U] = 
     | cct.map(t => f(t))(cbf)
map: [T, U, X, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Traversable[T],U,CC[U]])CC[U]
```

Brilliant. I has me a `map`! Let's use this thing!

```
scala> map(List(1, 2, 3, 4), (_ : Int).toString)
<console>:11: error: Cannot construct a collection of type List[java.lang.String] with elements of type java.lang.String based on a collection of type Traversable[Int].
              map(List(1, 2, 3, 4), (_ : Int).toString)
                 ^
```

Say, what?

---

### Observations

*I really can't help but think that Tony Morris' observations about this at the time were absolutely spot on. What did he say? He said "**Whatever that is, it is not map**". Look at how easy this is in scalaz-style*:

```
scala> trait Functor[F[_]] { def fmap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] }
defined trait Functor

scala> def map[F[_]: Functor, A, B](fa: F[A], f: A => B): F[B] = implicitly[Functor[F]].fmap(fa)(f)
map: [F[_], A, B](fa: F[A], f: A => B)(implicit evidence$1: Functor[F])F[B]
```

*Then*

```
scala> map(List(1, 2, 3, 4), (_ : Int).toString)
<console>:12: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Functor[List]
              map(List(1, 2, 3, 4), (_ : Int).toString)
                 ^
```

*So that*

```
scala> implicit val ListFunctor = new Functor[List] { def fmap[A, B](fa: List[A])(f: A => B) = fa map f }
ListFunctor: java.lang.Object with Functor[List] = $anon$1@4395cbcb

scala> map(List(1, 2, 3, 4), (_ : Int).toString)
res5: List[java.lang.String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Memo to self: **listen to Tony!**

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: The question is - how can I write such a method? Some of us try and show that we've made an effort to answer the question ourselves! I've added an edit for the tl;dr set

Comment: ...and I was *so close*. It's been answered on the twitter. I'll wait to see if it crops up here...

Comment: `TraversableOnce`'s `map` is not a functor map, but, then again, it never pretended to be one. It's design goals specifically precluded it from being a functor map.

Comment: Daniel: I don't deny it. I'm merely pointing out that it's brain-manglingly difficult to work with. Frankly, I should have been able to answer this myself

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you're running into is not necessarily `CanBuildFrom` itself, or the `Array` vs. `Seq` issue.  You're running into `String` which is *not* higher-kinded, but supports `map` against its `Char`s.

**SO: First a digression into Scala's collection design.**

What you need is a way to infer both the collection type (e.g. `String`, `Array[Int]`, `List[Foo]`) and the element type (e.g. `Char`, `Int`, `Foo` corresponding to the above).

Scala 2.10.x has added a  few "type classes" to help you.   For example, you can do the following:

```
class FilterMapImpl[A, Repr](val r: GenTraversableLike[A, Repr]) {
  final def filterMap[B, That](f: A => Option[B])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That =
    r.flatMap(f(_).toSeq)
 }
 implicit def filterMap[Repr, A](r: Repr)(implicit fr: IsTraversableOnce[Repr]): FilterMapImpl[fr.A,Repr] =
   new FilterMapImpl(fr.conversion(r))
```

There's two pieces here. FIRST,  your class that uses collections needs two type parameters:  The specific type of the collection `Repr` and the type of the elements `A`.

Next, you define an implicit method which only takes the collection type `Repr`.  You use the `IsTraversableOnce` (note: there is also an `IsTraversableLike`) to capture the element type of that collection.  You see this used in the type signature `FilterMapImpl[Repr, fr.A]`.

Now, part of this is because Scala does not use the same category for all of its "functor-like" operations.   Specifically, `map` is a useful method for `String`.  I can adjust all characters.  However, `String` can only be a `Seq[Char]`.  If I want to define a `Functor`, then my category can only contain the type `Char` and the arrows `Char => Char`.   This logic is captured in `CanBuildFrom`. However, since a `String` is a `Seq[Char]`, if you try to use a `map` in the category supported by `Seq`'s `map` method, then `CanBuildFrom` will alter your call to `map`.

We're essentially defining an "inheritance" relationship for our categories.  If you try to use the `Functor` pattern, we drop the type signature to the most specific category we can retain.  Call it what you will; that's a big motivating factor for the current collection design.

**End Digression, answer the question**

Now, because we're trying to infer a *lot* of types at the same time, I think this option has the fewest type annotations:

```
import collection.generic._

def map[Repr](col: Repr)(implicit tr: IsTraversableLike[Repr]) = new {
  def apply[U, That](f: tr.A => U)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, U, That]) = 
    tr.conversion(col) map f
}


scala> map("HI") apply (_ + 1 toChar )
warning: there were 2 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
res5: String = IJ
```

The important piece to note here is that `IsTraversableLike` captures a conversion from `Repr` to `TraversableLike` that allows you to use the `map` method.

**Option 2**

We also split the method call up a bit so that Scala can infer the types `Repr` and `U` before we define our anonymous function.   To avoid type annotations on anonymous functions, we must have all types *known* before it shows up.   Now, we can still have Scala infer some types, but lose things that are *implicitly* `Traversable` if we do this:

```
import collection.generic._
import collection._
def map[Repr <: TraversableLike[A, Repr], A, U, That](col: Repr with TraversableLike[A,Repr])(f: A => U)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, U, That]) = 
    col map f
```

Notice that we have to use `Repr with TraversableLike[A,Repr]`. It seems that most F-bounded types require this juggling.

In any case, now let's see what happens on something that extends `Traversable`:

```
scala> map(List(40,41))(_ + 1 toChar )
warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
res8: List[Char] = List(), *)
```

That's great.  However, if we want the same usage for `Array` and `String`, we have to go to a bit more work:

```
scala> map(Array('H', 'I'): IndexedSeq[Char])(_ + 1 toChar)(breakOut): Array[Char]
warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
res14: Array[Char] = Array(I, J)

scala> map("HI": Seq[Char])(_ + 1 toChar)(breakOut) : String
warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
res11: String = IJ
```

There are two pieces to this usage:

1. We have to use a type annotation for the implicit conversion from `String`/`Array` → `Seq`/`IndexedSeq`.
2. We have to use `breakOut` for our `CanBuildFrom` and type-annotate the expected return value.

This is solely because the type `Repr <: TraversableLike[A,Repr]` does not include `String` or `Array`, since those use implicit conversions.

**Option 3**

You can place all the implicits together at the end and require the user to annotate types.   Not the most elegant solution, so I think I'll avoid posting it unless you'd really like to see it.

SO, basically if you want to include `String` and `Array[T]` as collections, you have to jump through some hoops. This category restriction for map applies to both `String` and `BitSet` functors in Scala.

I hope that helps. Ping me if you have any more questions.

Comment: If adding this to string makes the general solution less than ideal because it's really a different problem, why not just create one-off map for string and allow a conversion to `List[Char]` for anything complicated? Then you don't have to worry about the string case anymore.

Comment: BitSet and String both have limited categories.   Part of the issue is that in scala you can pass a String where a Seq[Char] is expected and a BitSet where a Set[Int] is expected.   For one its an implicit (which hurts the solution) for the other it's inheritance, which forces your signature of map.    All things combined create what you see.

Answer (score 11):

There are actually several questions in there...

Let's start with your last attempt:

```
scala> def map[T, U, X, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)
 (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Traversable[T], U, CC[U]]): CC[U] = 
  cct.map(t => f(t))(cbf)
```

This one does compiles but does not work because, according to your type signature, it has to look for an implicit `CanBuildFrom[Traversable[Int], String, List[String]]` in scope, and there just isn't one. If you were to create one by hand, it would work.

Now the previous attempt:

```
scala> def map[T, U, X, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)
 (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[T], U, CC[U]]): CC[U] = 
  cct.map(t => f(t))(cbf)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[CC[T],U,CC[U]]
 required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Traversable[T],U,CC[U]]
       cct.map(t => f(t))(cbf)
                          ^
```

This one does not compile because the implicit `CanBuildFrom` in `Traversable` is hardcoded to accept only a `Traversable` as `From` collection. However, as pointed out in the other answer, `TraversableLike` knows about the actual collection type (it's its second type parameter), so it defines `map` with the proper `CanBuildFrom[CC[T], U, CC[U]]` and everybody is happy. Actually, `TraversableLike` inherits this `map` method from `scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic`, so this is even more generic:

```
scala> import scala.collection.generic._
import scala.collection.generic._

scala> def map[T, U, CC[T] <: FilterMonadic[T, CC[T]]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)
 |  (implicit cbf:  CanBuildFrom[CC[T], U, CC[U]]): CC[U] = cct.map(f)
warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
map: [T, U, CC[T] <: scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic[T,CC[T]]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[CC[T],U,CC[U]])CC[U]

scala> map(List(1,2,3,4), (_:Int).toString + "k")
res0: List[String] = List(1k, 2k, 3k, 4k)
```

Finally, the above does not work with arrays because `Array` is not a `FilterMonadic`. But there is an implicit conversion from `Array` to `ArrayOps`, and the latter implements `FilterMonadic`. So if you add a view bound in there, you get something that works for arrays as well:

```
scala> import scala.collection.generic._
import scala.collection.generic._

scala> def map[T, U, CC[T]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)
 |  (implicit cbf:  CanBuildFrom[CC[T], U, CC[U]], 
 |   ev: CC[T] => FilterMonadic[T,CC[T]]): CC[U] = cct.map(f)
warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
map: [T, U, CC[T]](cct: CC[T], f: T => U)(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[CC[T],U,CC[U]], implicit ev: CC[T] => scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic[T,CC[T]])CC[U]

scala> map(List(1,2,3,4), (_:Int).toString + "k")
res0: List[String] = List(1k, 2k, 3k, 4k)

scala> map(Array(1,2,3,4), (_:Int).toString + "k")
res1: Array[String] = Array(1k, 2k, 3k, 4k)
```

**EDIT:**
There is also a way to make it work for `String` and co: just remove the higher kinds on the input/output collection, using a third one in the middle:

```
def map[T, U, From, To, Middle](cct: From, f: T => U)
 (implicit ev: From => FilterMonadic[T, Middle], 
  cbf: CanBuildFrom[Middle,U,To]): To = cct.map(f)
```

This works on `String` and even on `Map[A,B]`:

```
scala> map(Array(42,1,2), (_:Int).toString)
res0: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(42, 1, 2)

scala> map(List(42,1,2), (_:Int).toString)
res1: List[java.lang.String] = List(42, 1, 2)

scala> map("abcdef", (x: Char) => (x + 1).toChar)
res2: String = bcdefg

scala> map(Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 42 -> "hi!"), (a:(Int, String)) => (a._2, a._1))
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, hi! -> 42)
```

Tested with 2.9.2. But as jsuereth pointed out, there is the wonderful `IsTraversableLike` in 2.10 that is better fitted for this.

Comment: FilterMonadic is really intended to be used with the `withFilter` method.  Neat trick though.  You're using `FilterMonadic` to jump the same type hurdles we added `IsTraversableOnce` to Scala 2.10 for.

Comment: @jsuereth thanks, I didn't know about `IsTraversableOnce` and `IsTraversableLike`, this is a very nice addition. I edited my answer to get to the same result with Scala < 2.10.

Comment: I hope you don't mind - I'm switching the accepted answer on the basis that it's lovely and up to date with 2.10 and the `IsTraversableLike` plus the type member is really neat.

Answer (score 8):

Is this it?

```
def map[A,B,T[X] <: TraversableLike[X,T[X]]]
  (xs: T[A])(f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[T[A],B,T[B]]): T[B] = xs.map(f)

map(List(1,2,3))(_.toString)
// List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609398/returning-same-collection-type-differently-parameterised).

Comment: I'd be interested if you could explain why the use of `TraversableLike` instead of `Traversable` has worked here and I'm also interested in an answer that will work for Arrays

Comment: @oxbow_lakes `Traversable` methods generate `Traversable` collections. A `TraversableLike` generate collections which are _like_ `Traversable` -- that's it's second parameter. When one say `List[T] extends Traversable[T] with TraversableLike[T, List[T]]`, it means you can use `List[T]` as a `Traversable[T]`, but you can _also_ have it return `List[T]` as result, if appropriate.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Now, as for `Array`, that's way tougher -- in practice, you need to create separate methods to handle `String` and `Array`, or not work with collections that do not take type parameters, such as `String` and `BitSet`. Alternatively, see the type class create on Scala 2.10 to simplify all this -- it's mentioned on my Scala 2.10.0 presentation.