# How can a method accept a (T <: Seq)[A] and return T[B] -- the same type of sequence with a different type parameter?

Tags: scala

I want to implement a method that accepts a sequence of one element type and returns a sequence of a different element type. How can I do this generically so that the same subclass of Sequence gets returned?

My method currently looks like this:

```
def lookerUpper(ids : Seq[String], someOtherInfo : Int) : Seq[UsefulData] = {
    ... retrieve data for each id ...
}
```

I'd like it to be more generic, so that whatever kind of sequence (of strings) is passed in  is also the kind of sequence (of UsefulData) returned. Vector and List, especially, or as general as we can make it.

Can this be expressed in Scala's type system? "Returns the same type as this argument, except with a different type parameter."

Comment: You should use the same kind of builder strategy I use in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846

Answer (score 3):

For a complete answer, you should look at my rather long question and answer about builders (note: as of September 2012, Miles' alternate version does not work in either 2.9 or the latest 2.10).

Here's a framework to get you started (note the strange formatting of the explicit and implicit parameter blocks in order to avoid overly-long lines for display on SO):

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

case class UsefulData(data: Int) {}

def lookerUpper[C[String]](
  ids: C[String], someOtherInfo: Int
)(
  implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[C[String],UsefulData,C[UsefulData]],
  ev: C[String] => Iterable[String]
): C[UsefulData] = {
  val b = cbf()
  val i = ev(ids)
  i.foreach{ s => b += UsefulData(s.length + someOtherInfo) }
  b.result 
}
```

And observe that it works:

```
scala> lookerUpper(Vector("salmon","cod"),2)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[UsefulData] = 
  Vector(UsefulData(8), UsefulData(5))

scala> lookerUpper(Array("salmon","cod"),2)
res1: Array[UsefulData] = 
  Array(UsefulData(8), UsefulData(5))
```

---

Edit: if you only care about subclasses of `TraversableLike` (which `Array` is not), and you are going to use standard collection operations to do all the work, then you can use the [answer to 8609398](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609398) as Luigi points out.  (Maybe I should move this answer there as another perspective.)