# Why are there no methods toVector (like toList, toArray) in standard collection types?

Tags: scala

If we are supposed to use **Vector** as the default Sequence type, why are there no methods toVector (like toList, toArray) in standard collection types?

In prototyping stage, is it okay to conform all collections to Seq type and use toSeq on all collection-returns (cast everything to Seq)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normally you should be more concerned with the interface that the collection implements rather than its concrete type, i.e. you should think in terms of `Seq`, `LinearSeq`, and `IndexedSeq` rather than `List`, `Array`, and `Vector`, which are concrete implementations. So arguably there shouldn't be `toList` and `toArray` either, but I guess they're there because they're so fundamental.

The `toIndexedSeq` method in practice provides you with a `Vector`, unless a collection overrides this in order to provide a more efficient implementation. You can also make a Vector with `Vector() ++ c` where `c` is your collection.

Comment: So it is a good practice to set all function parameter types to Iterable instead of specific types (unless you need them for some specific functionality/performance)?

Comment: If you need it to cover all Iterables then by all means do that, but the compiler won't complain when you pass your method a Map by mistake! I think in OO in general, the theory is that you're supposed to accept that most general type possible and return the most specific. With collections, making the accepted types too general will mean the returned type will also be very general (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8235462/770361). So in practice you methods taking `List` etc. `Seq` is a good compromise to use IMO.

Comment: I think there ought to be `toVector` anyway. Sometimes this whole code-to-the-interface thing is important, like at API boundaries, but most of the time you're just trying to get work done and the lack of `toVector` is just annoying. `Vector` is a great general-purpose collection; the uses of `List` and `Array` are rather specialized.

Comment: @SethTisue - Agreed.  I have a standard `toVector` enrichment.

Answer (score 3):

Scala 2.10 will come with a method `.to[C[_]]` so that you can write `.to[List]`, `.to[Array]`, `.to[Vector]`, or any other compatible `C`.

Comment: And `.to[Seq]` produces a Vector, at least for the cases I tried.

Comment: @AmigoNico, that's because `Seq` is a trait, not a concrete type.

Comment: Yes, sorry -- was just pointing out that Vector was chosen in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Scala 2.10 adds not only .to[Vector], but .toVector, as well:

In TraversableOnce trait inherited by collections and iterators:

```
abstract def toVector: Vector[A]
```