# Function which generically takes a type and returns the same type

Tags: scala, generics, collections, functional-programming, type-theory

I am having a tough time understanding why the Scala compiler is unhappy about this function definition:

```
def trimNonWordCharacters[T <: Iterable[String]](items: T): T =
     items map { _.replaceAll("\\W", "") }
```

Here is the [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) output:

```
scala> def trimNonWordCharacters[T <: Iterable[String]](items: T): T =
     items map { _.replaceAll("\\W", "") }
<console>:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Iterable[java.lang.String]
 required: T
       def trimNonWordCharacters[T <: Iterable[String]](items: T): T = items map { _.replaceAll("\\W", "") }
```

The goal is to pass in any implementation of an Iterable and get the same type of back out. Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235462/returning-original-collection-type-in-generic-method

Comment: @LuigiPlinge That question did not need `CanBuildFrom`, since `filter` doesn't require it. This question is very similar, and the _title_ of that question certainly covers it, but here a little bit more is required to make it work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `map` method on `Iterable` returns an `Iterable`, so even if `T` is a subclass of `Iterable`, it's `map` method will return `Iterable`.

To get better typing, you'd have to write it like this:

```
import scala.collection.IterableLike
def trimNonWordCharacters[T <: Iterable[String]](items: T with IterableLike[String, T]): T =
     items map { _.replaceAll("\\W", "") }
```

However, that won't work either, because there's no information that let a map on `T` to generate another `T`. For example, mapping a `BitSet` into a `String` cannot result in a `BitSet`. So we need something else: something that teaches how to build a `T` from a `T`, where the mapped elements are of type `String`. Like this:

```
import scala.collection.IterableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
def trimNonWordCharacters[T <: Iterable[String]]
                         (items: T with IterableLike[String, T])
                         (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[T, String, T]): T =
     items map { _.replaceAll("\\W", "") }
```

Comment: Thank you so much- Your explanation is very informative and now I finally know a way to use `CanBuildFrom` (!)

Answer (score 0):

*[Entering as an answer rather than a comment because code in comments doesn't format properly]*

@Daniel, thanks for the explanation, I also found it useful.  As Iterable derives from IterableLike, the following also seems to work, and is slightly more compact:

```
import scala.collection.IterableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
def trimNonWordCharacters[T <: IterableLike[String, T]]
 (items: T)
 (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[T, String, T]): T =
 items map { _.replaceAll("\\W", "") }
```