# Return the same collection type after performing multiple operations on the collection

Tags: scala, generics, collections

Using an implicit `CanBuildFrom` parameter seems to work for returning the same type of collection only when one manipulation is made to the collection.  Is there a simple way to allow more logic-complex methods return the same type as the parameter type?

Given the following code:

```
def trimCharacters(items: Iterable[String]): Iterable[String] =
  items map (_.replaceAll("\\W", "")) map (_.replaceAll("\\w", ""))
```

If you change both the collection type of `items` and the return type to a subtype valid subtype of `Iterable` the code will still compile.  I want to generalize this so that the return type is chosen by the caller according to the type of `Iterable` provided.

[This answer utilizing `CanBuildFrom`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019784/1072626) comes close, but only does the first `map` from the original:

```
def trimNonWordCharacters[T <: Seq[String]]
    (items: T with SeqLike[String, T])
    (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[T, String, T]): T =
  items map (_.replaceAll("\\W", ""))
```

The simple act of performing the second map:

```
def trimCharacters[T <: Seq[String]]
    (items: T with SeqLike[String, T])
    (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[T, String, T]): T =
  items.map(_.replaceAll("\\W", "")).map(_.replaceAll("\\w", ""))
```

breaks compilation:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Seq[String]
[error]  required: T
```

Is there a change that would allow this to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pulled in the implicit `CanBuildFrom` but you're not employing it.

```
def trimCharacters[T <: Seq[String]](items: T with SeqLike[String, T]
                                   )(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[T, String, T]
                                   ): T = {
  val builder = cbf(items)
  builder.sizeHint(items)
  items.map(_.replaceAll("\\W","")).map(_.replaceAll("\\w","")).foreach(builder += _)
  builder.result()
}
```

BTW, in this case the `map`s can be collapsed.

```
items.map(_.replaceAll("\\W", "").replaceAll("\\w", "")).foreach(builder += _)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the generalized solution is as follows? First, do all the desired manipulations to get the desired resulting collection.  Then, iterate over the desired result using `+=` on the builder to append each item.  Finally, return the result produced by builder `result()`.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the general outline. Have a look at the way it's done in the [TraversableLike source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L1) for some simple straight forward examples.

Comment: It is a shame that `CanBuildFrom` is can not just used implicitly like it is when only one operation is performed.